# Jenkins | Cocoapods | Swift | error: no such module 'RealmSwift'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jenkins, swift3

error: no such module 'RealmSwift'

import RealmSwift

While building a project from Xcode, it's working fine. Building it from Jenkins,gives me the above mentioned error.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

(2 failures)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

My Pod file looks like below

```
target 'MyProject' do
use_frameworks!
# Pods for MyProject
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleTagManager','~> 3.15.0'
pod 'RealmSwift','~> 2.1'

target 'MyProjectTests' do
# Pods for testing
end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do
# Pods for testing
end   
end
```

Comment: Please show your jenkins build command and logs.

Comment: i have updated the post..

Comment: it's not a build command. An example is: `ARCHIVE_DAY=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
ARCHIVE_TIME=$(date +%H.%M.%S)
ARCHIVE_PATH="$HOME_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/${ARCHIVE_DAY}/MyFirstSwiftApp ${ARCHIVE_DAY} ${ARCHIVE_TIME}.xcarchive"
set -o pipefail \
    && DEVELOPER_DIR="${XCODE}" Scripts/xcbuild-safe.sh -workspace MyFirstSwiftApp.xcworkspace \
    -scheme ${SCHEME} \
    -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
    -archivePath "${ARCHIVE_PATH}" \
    clean archive`

Comment: To formulate my concern differently: which target/scheme are you building in your jenkins job? Did you try to create a minimal case project to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have versioned your `Pods` directory.

You can either remove `Pods` from your .gitignore, or add a `pod install` command inside each jenkins script.

Comment: .gitignore   
# CocoaPods # Pods/